# Is 2hr 25min sufficient for switching from an international flight (EWR Terminal B) to a domestic flight (EWR Terminal C)?

Tags: short-connections, united-airlines, british-airways, ewr

I will be arriving by BA at Terminal B of EWR at 14:05 from India (the flight stops at Heathrow). I will then have to go to Terminal C of EWR for my United flight that leaves at 16:30 to Syracuse. I would like to know if the following itinerary could be followed:

- Arrive at 14:05.
- Immigration and baggage taken by 15:30 (SUPER MAX).
- Take AirTrain from Terminal B of EWR to Terminal C of EWR (10 minutes, i.e. I'll be there by 15:45 maximum).
- At Terminal C, check into flight to Syracuse by 16:00.
- Flight to Syracuse leaves at 16:30.

Would I need more time at the Immigration counters or while collecting my baggage?

Finally, would I be able to reach Terminal C on time for my next flight and be able to go through Security and complete the other measures on time?

Comment: Is EWR to Syracuse part of the same ticket as the one from India to EWR ? In other words, are your bags getting checked through to Syracuse ?

Comment: No, India to EWR is through BA and EWR to SYR is through UA. They're not in the same itinerary and thus bags will have to be re-checked in at Terminal C!

Comment: Without arrival delays for the flight in to EWR, you should be fine. Remember that if you miss your second flight, UA cannot be held responsible since it is a separate ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, 90 minutes for immigration at EWR is quite safe. To be on the *safer* side, ensure that you queue up soon after you exit the aircraft. Your seat position will also effect where in the queue you end up. Try, if possible, to get a seat towards the front of the aircraft (numerically lower seat numbers). Also, at 1400 hrs not all counters will be open. This may delay immigration a bit. Of course, it also depends on whether someone ahead of you has an immigration issue and holds a counter busy.

With regard to the second part, make sure you actually can check in till 1600 for a 1630 flight.